# Where to download Wolfenstein: Enemy Territory for linux?

Tags: linux, games

Hey Guys,
I'm using KUBUNTU 10.10 I would like to use Wolfenstein: Enemy Territory for linux, I know this game is free, right?

Please could someone give me the list of the last version of the game?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Take a look here, there's a whole tutorial on how to set it up on Ubuntu (including the download):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnemyTerritory